# Finding all possible combinations of int[] array, constrained by length in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, combinations

```
int[] listOfValues = {1, 2, 5, 2, 6};
```

I need to be able to find all pair combinations of this array, including repetitions. Each value in the array comes from a deck of cards. So, if the value "2" appears twice in the array, for example, we can assume that these are two *different* values, and as such, need to be treated separately.

Sample of expected pairs of cards:

```
{1, 2}
{1, 2}
{2, 1}
{2, 1}
{2, 2}
{1, 5}
{1, 6}
etc.......
```

These separate int[] results will then need to be added to a List (if you can even add duplicate int[] values to a list, that is!), once all possible values have been found.

I have looked for a few hours online, and can't seem to get any of the solutions working for my particular task.

Does anyone have any ideas please?

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26050/Permutations-Combinations-and-Variations-using-C-G

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really do homework on your own. Or at least try it first. You haven't provided code, so I cannot ethically give you the full solution.

However, this will get you started:

Think about it as if you were to do it by hand. Most people would pick the first value and the second value and write them down. Then they would write that pair backwards. Then they would do the first value and the third, then backwards, and so on and so on.

It would look something like:

{1,2}

{2,1}

{1,5}

{5,1}

{1,2}

{2,1}

{1,6}

{6,1}

{2,5}  -Now we iterate again, starting with the second value

So how would we express that in code? **Nested loops!**

Here is the skeleton of an algorithm to solve your problem:

```
List<int[]> pairs = new List<int[]>();

for(int x = 0; x < listOfValues.Length - 1; x++)
{
    for(int y = x+1; y < listOfValues.Length; y++)
    {
        // Create an array of the [x] position and [y] position of listOfValues
        // Create another array, except swap the positions {[y],[x]}

        // Add both arrays to the "pairs" List
    }
}
```

Try to understand what this code is doing. Then fill in the blanks. You should get the correct answer. Always make sure to understand why, though. Also, try to see if you can figure out any improvements to this code.

Comment: This has kick started my work massively, thank you for this.

Answer (score 0):

With linq you could do it this way.

```
int[] listOfValues = { 1, 2, 5, 2, 6 };
        var combination = listOfValues.Select(i => listOfValues.Select(i1 => new Tuple<int, int>(i, i1)).ToList())
            .ToList()
            .SelectMany(list => list.Select(x => x)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to Clay07g's post, I was able to resolve the problem with the following code:

```
public static List<int[]> getCardCombos(int[] values)
{
  List<int[]> pairs = new List<int[]>();

  for (int x = 0; x < values.Length - 1; x++)
  {
    for (int y = x + 1; y < values.Length; y++)
    {
      int firstValue = values[x];
      int secondValue = values[y];

      // Create an array of the [x] position and [y] position of listOfValues 
      int[] xAndY = { firstValue, secondValue};
      // Create another array, except swap the positions {[y],[x]}
      int[] yAndX = { secondValue, firstValue };

      pairs.Add(xAndY);
      pairs.Add(yAndX);
      // Add both arrays to the "pairs" List
    }
  }
  return pairs;
}
```